# Number of ways to divide a group of n people into groups of size m to m-1

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A group of n people will be partitioned into groups given a maximum group size of m like so:

There are $⌈\frac{n}{m}⌉$ amount of groups in total. A person is added to the first group and then the second group and so on in a loop until there is no more people to add. How many combinations of groups can be created?

Or more formally:

How many different partitions does the set $\{1,…,n\}$ have when there are $⌈\frac{n}{m}⌉$ subsets in total where $⌊\frac{n}{⌈\frac{n}{m}⌉}⌋$ of them has a cardinality of $m$ and $n\%⌈\frac{n}{m}⌉$ of them has a cardinality of $m-1$?

Where $n≥m⋅2-1≥3$

$\%$ is the modulos operator

By combination I mean the order of people in each group and the order of groups does not matter.

Comment: "*and the order of groups does not matter*"  You can pick who the people who will eventually be in a full-sized group are, then choose who the people sharing a group with the shortest person is, pick who the people sharing a group with the shortest remaining person is, etc... then do the same for those people in the undersized groups.  For example for $n=17$ and $m=4$ we will have one group of size five and three groups of size four.  There will be $\binom{17}{12}\binom{11}{3}\binom{7}{3}$ such arrangements.

Comment: "*How many different* **subsets** *does the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ have when...*"  you mean to use the word *partitions* here, not subsets.

Comment: Yes, I meant partitions. I made a mistake regarding the amount of subsets that has a cardinality of $m$ vs. $m-1$ and I have edited it, so it is correct now.